# Openresty: ngx.var vs ngx.ctx

Tags: nginx, openresty

What's the use case differences between `ngx.var` and `ngx.ctx`? When should one use `var` vs `ctx`? Are there any performance differences one should know about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely not a subject matter expert but from what I've gathered on my search adventure is: ngx.var is more expensive than ngx.ctx, also ngx.var only works with strings.

Comment: Actually I think this is an answer.